# MySql search string that matches at least 2 substrings with regexp

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm trying to create a regexp expression in order to match some strings in my db.

My initial solution was something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn REGEXP 'a1|a2|a3'
```

but with this solutions it matches every string that contains at least one needle of the haystack. What i'm trying to achieve is to match every needle or at least 2 of them.

Examples:

Wanted string: 'My little foo with bar'

1. ['little', 'foo'] => Matches
2. ['little', 'foobar'] => Not matches
3. ['my', 'bar', 'little'] => Matches

Comment: I think you should look into `FULL TEXT SEARCH` instead

Answer (score 1):

This is ugly, and slow, but here's a way:

```
    WHERE (myColumn LIKE '%a1%')
        + (myColumn LIKE '%a2%')
        + (myColumn LIKE '%a3%') >= 2;
```

Note that a boolean expression (such as the result of `LIKE`) is `1` for true or `0` for false.

`LIKE` is faster than `REGEXP` and `LIKE` is sufficient for my suggestion, so I switched to it.

If you need to match *words*, the `FULLTEXT` is probably a better way to go.  However, doing my `>= 2` trick may not be possible.